# Word Documents.Count Is incorrect from MS Access 2016

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word, com, automation

I have an MS Access application that spawns a single Word Document at any one time. However the "Word.Application" object doesnt seem to be closing properly, before the next attemt to open a different document (i'll work that out). It errors when attempting to return to a document previously opened, reporting it to be already open. Well indeed Process Explorer reveals it is indeed still open. So I was intending to count the number of docs open and if there were none, close the Word Application.
 But in the course of trying to get it to close properly I discover that if I do this:

```
Dim objWord As word.application
Dim doc As Object

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    objWord.visible = False
    Set doc = objWord.Documents.Open(wordDocFilespec) ...
```

Inspecting the watch window objWord.Documents.Count is 1, as you might expect and it was 0 prior to the "Open" except I already have other Word documents not related to this application Open on the desktop! Is it not supposed to Count the total number of Word docs open, rather than just the apps opened via this object declaration?

Comment: You creating a new separate instance, so count() is restricted to the new instance of word. If you want to grab existing, then use GetObject() in place of createObject

Comment: Yes @AlbertD.Kallal Thankyou

Comment: Considering the broader implications of your situation, if you're having trouble releasing a document that implies you're re-using it. Is there a reason you're working with a single document rather than creating them from a TEMPLATE?

Comment: Well a function includes a parameter of a filespec that will be either docx or doc, and may exist or not have yet been created. I am using doc.SaveAs to alter the format for readonly purposes to html - later when use has been made the read-only html version will be closed - the count was important to check if I should also close the application, i.e are other documents also open. It was agoing wrong on two fronts - I I thought the doc needed to be closed. And I hadnt realised that the SaveAs keeps the doc instantiated but in the new format,  which I didnt thnk I needed to close.